# Order By Date and truncate date strings in Angular

Tags: angularjs, filtering

I have a json file with a released field that comes back with such format:

released: "2002-01-28"

I intend to display them sorted by date (earlier first) and only showing the year. I've used the truncate module (in my example, release: 4) and so far its showing only the first 4 characters, but I haven't succeed using orderby to sort it correctly.

Any pointers?

Also, in some items the released field comes back empty, any quick way to display just a "unknown" instead of a blank space?

Thanks!

```
<li ng-show="versions" ng-repeat="version in versions | filter: '!file' | orderBy: version.released">
  {{version.released | release:4}} - {{version.format}} - {{version.label}}
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can show unknown by doing `{{version.released || 'unknown'}}`.

If you only want to show the year do this `{{ (version.released | date : date : 'YYYY' ) || 'unknown'}}`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a date formatting filter I use. It takes a date and converts it into whatever format you wish, in your case, 'yyyy'. Bind the raw date stamp in your template and then 'orderBy' should work fine. This is how I always do it. Oh, you might not want the replace() function... that was specific to my last project.

```
.filter('DateFormat', function($filter){
    return function(text){
        if(text !== undefined){
            var tempdate = new Date(text.replace(/-/g,"/"));
            return $filter('date')(tempdate, "MMM. dd, yyyy");
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: In my case I should state (tempdate, "yyyy - mm - dd");??